# How to calculate total of an increasing variable

Tags: c, variables, math

If there's a variable called a, that's constantly counting up, but resetting to 0 when it hits a certain number, how can I calculate the total of that variable? For example:

```
    int count = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (true) {
         count++;
         a = count % 1000;
         total = ...;
    }
```

Where "total" would be the total value of a, which would go past 1000. Simply adding it on won't work, since it will go total+=1, total+=2, total+=3, etc. How can I calculate this every loop? Thanks for any help. :) I'm using C by the way, although it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: `total += a;` is not?

Comment: doesn't `count` hold the total ? I'm guessing that you didn't really explain your problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int getA(){
    static int count = 1;
    if(count == 1000) count = 1;
    return count++;
}

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    int a, total;

    while (true) {
        a = getA();
        if(i == 1001) break;
        total += a;
         ++i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);//499501 = 1+2+...998+999+1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really, think of it this way. A function called getA() returns an increasing number which resets back to 0 when it reaches 1000. Total needs to store the total value of getA(), as if the resets weren't there. So for example, getA() returns 50, total = 50, getA() returns 51, total = 51, getA() returns 999, total = 999, but then getA() resets to 0, and soon returns 1, and total should now equal 1001, and not 1.

Comment: @MrCherno i was rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.In your program `total` is in no way related to the value of `a`.

```
           int count = 1;
            int a = 0;
            int total = 0;
            while ((count+1001)%1001) {                     
                 a = (count+1001) % 1001;
                 count++;
                 total = total+a;
            }
           printf("The sum of 1000 numbers is %d",

          total);
```